# module.exports = app More than One Require

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a lambda function on AWS and I'm looking to require more than one file for "app". Apologies, I'm not great with Node yet.

In a routes.js file I have the following...

```
module.exports = app => {
    require("./event.routes.js")(app);
    require("./eventtemplate.routes.js")(app);
};
```

Normally there is only 1 require() between the {}. But I require both files as I've separated out the code into two different files for clarity. When I comment out the second require all is good and the runtime can find the functions in event.routes.js. But with the second require in there. It does not. Do I need to somehow name them? They do have similarly named functions. But they are contained within their "Event" and "EventTemplate" object in those different files.

Here's the event.routes.js file...

```
module.exports = app => {
    const controller = require("../controllers/event.controller.js");

    // Create a new event
    app.post("/event", controller.create);
};
```

My eventtemplate.routes.js has similarly named functions. So I'm guessing this is the issue. My attempt to make things cleaner has broken things. Wondering if there is a better way to separate out things?

** UPDATE **

As requested, here is eventTemplate.routes.js...

```
module.exports = app => {
    const controller = require("../controllers/eventtemplate.controller.js");
    
    // Create a new EventTemplate
    app.post("/event/template", controller.create);
);
```

Comment: Please show the code for both `event.routes.js` and `eventtemplate.routes.js`.  There is no name collision between them (they are each in their own module namespace) so naming is not the issue.  There is apparently an implementation problem in one of the two files.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok done. Added the code above. Let me know if there's any more that would help. Trying to be brief but enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. It was just that I had a misnamed function in my controller file that was being referenced from my route file. I had truncated the source listing for brevity but I would've had to post the controller code as well to see the error.

However thanks for the comments. It did steer me in the right direction to know that what I was doing was fine and correct and was just a typo. Thank you!